# Why does std::remove_pointer also remove const qualifier

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

Consider the following code:

```
typedef const std::string const_string_type;
cout << std::is_const<const_string_type>::value << endl;
cout << std::is_const<std::remove_pointer<const_string_type>::type>::value << endl;
```

This outputs

```
1
0
```

That means that `std::remove_pointer<const_string_type>::type` removed the `const` qualifier from the type.  My understanding is that `std::remove_pointer` is supposed to produce the exact same type (qualifiers and all) if the type is not a pointer.

Is this correct behavior, or is this possibly a compiler-implementation issue?

Comment: What compiler do you use? (I get with g++ 4.7.2: Result: 1,1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a compiler bug.  According to the standard (§20.9.7.5,
Table 56): "template  struct remove_pointer; : 
If T has type '(possibly cv-qualified) pointer to T1' then the member
typedef type shall name T1; otherwise, it shall name T."  It
should never remove any `const` or `volatile` qualifiers from
the results.

Comment: For the record, GCC 4.8.1 does the right thing. I have no idea what compiler the OP was using, however.

Comment: +1 Likewise with clang 3.2. (at least on my Mac). Each of the decls at [this live sample](http://ideone.com/5ses6x) that require initialization because the const is properly carried over are sufficiently marked.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not remove the const (only removes qualifiers from the pointer not the pointed to type), from [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) this is a possible implementation.

```
template< class T > struct remove_pointer                    {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T*>                {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* const>          {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* volatile>       {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* const volatile> {typedef T type;};
```

The result is actually a bug in the compiler, it should not remove the const of the pointed to type in any situation.

**EDIT** here is a quote from a table in the standard confirming it. `20.9.7.5
Pointer modifications`

> template  struct remove_pointer;
>   If T has type “(possibly cv-qualified) pointer to T1” then the member  typedef type shall name T1; otherwise, it shall name T.

Comment: -1. It doesn't remove in the quoted implementation. `const_string_type` is not a pointer, so the first case applies.

Comment: This states that remove_pointer will remove top-level qualifiers. The pointed-to type should retain it's qualifiers. This looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: @Nawaz What do you mean, the type inside has had const and or volatile removed?

Comment: @Nawaz but if it was indeed a pointer it would remove the const right?

Comment: @aaronman: As the per the quoted implementation, yes. But that is not the question.

Comment: @aaronman From the pointer, yes.  But since the pointer won't remain anyway, it's irrelevant.

Comment: I wouldn't remove the downvote, because it is still wrong. Is "yes" the answer to the question posted by the OP?

Comment: @Nawaz the result is a bug in the compiler no?

Comment: @Nawaz It's completely wrong, or at least misleading, because even if the type is a pointer, it doesn't remove a `const` from `T`.

Comment: @JamesKanze well which one is it, you say no Nawaz said yes it does, you don't think it's cruel to be so harsh on an answer that at least one of you is incorrect about

Comment: @JamesKanze just to be clear I have no problem amending, but what can I do if two people criticize for opposite things

Comment: @aaronman The standard says nothing about removing const from the resulting type.  The implementation you cite doesn't remove const from the resulting type.  The typedef `type` never has an `const` removed.

Comment: @aaronman: **I did NOT say "yes".  It is you who said "yes" and I asked: does *your yes* answer the OP's question?**

Comment: @Nawaz I understand now, sorry that the implementation on a well regarded site is wrong and I trusted it totally my fault

Comment: The implementation is correct. It is the exact implementation on my rig (Apple LLVM 4.2, clang 3.2). It is the *compiler* that is broken in the OP's case.

Comment: @aaronman: The problem is that you didn't understand the quoted implementation. Even according to that, your answer should be "NO". So please don't blame the site when you don't understand it.

Comment: @WhozCraig so the implementation on cppreference does **not** remove const?

Comment: @aaronman: That is a different question altogether. As I said, even according to the quoted implementation, your answer should be "NO"

Comment: No it doesn't. [See this example](http://ideone.com/5ses6x), take it locally and try it on your rig, including removing the initializers. If your rig lets *any* of the first three decls by without initializers, its wrong.

Comment: @bstamour btw thanks for being the only one who actually explained it correctly, unfortunately I didn't notice it at first in the mess of comments

Comment: *"so apparently the implementation on cppreference is wrong"*. Sorry, it is not that *apparent* to me. Please post the correct implementation if you think cppreference's implementation is wrong. At least do tell us what *exactly* is wrong with it.

Comment: @Nawaz it's not wrong, but on the other hand the only person who explained what was happening correctly is bstamour, anyway I changed my whole answer so w/e